# MTP oddities on Windows 10

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, windows, lg, mtp

I had always used USB Mass Storage to transfer files from/to devices to my PC (currently Windows 10) but my new phone (LG X Power with Android 6) no longer supports it so I'm left with MTP, which appears to be significantly slower (but I don't know who to blame). Data transfer rate is acceptable but:

- Creating an empty folder on the phone from Windows explorer can take up to a minute.
- I can't move files within the phone (copy never ends, no matter file size).

This happened with whatever MTP drivers Windows 10 bundle. I downloaded the drivers provided by LG but nothing improved.

I asked LG and their reply was that «USB drivers do not support Windows 10» and I need to find a computer running «Windows XP SP3 ~ Windows 8.1».

My questions:

1. Is it true that current Windows version does not have first class drivers for MTP?
2. Is there some way to address those two issues I suffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MTP does not support simultaneous read/write, nor edit.  This has nothing to do with Windows 10.  (See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol#History)

If you want to move files within the device, you will need to either (1) do so from within the device or (b) first copy the files to your PC, then copy them back to the new location on the phone.

The goal of MTP is to prevent data integrity issues by abstracting away the underlying filesystem and preventing simultaneous access; for this reason, it is strictly less powerful than USB Mass Storage.

Comment: Thank you. No wonder LG support guys have less idea than me. BTW, is the 1 minute delay to create empty folders something to expect?